# Reconsidering custom close reasons on Math.SE

Tags: discussion, feature-request, closing, close-reasons

In the discussion [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/20108/how-to-deal-with-just-google-it-questions/20119?noredirect=1#comment76725_20119) meta thread it was discovered, that the current custom close reason **missing context or other details** is much less specific than the other close reasons.
The answer to [what is context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960/86940) lists six different bullets defining the scope of the close reason. In short these are

- Lack of effort ("Include your work")
- Lack of motivation
- Missing source
- Missing mathematical backgroud of OP
- Missing references
- Missing definitions

Now while some of these may be combined into one bullet (For example "missing source", and "missing references" could be), this still defines a **very wide scope** for the close reason, leading to the OP being displayed a close message wich might not accurately address the problems of the post.

On SO there are five custom close reasons, while we only have one here. Adding another one wouldn't be much of a problem. So I propose we **narrow down the scope** of the "missing context or other details" reason by splitting it into carefully chosen categories.

The goal of this post is to

1. Find out wich reasons can be grouped into small categories with a uniform and useful description, so than an OP knows exactly why his question was closed
2. Find a good, informative message for each of these reasons such that misunderstanding is as unlikely as possible

**Suggestions**
I will now present my idea. Please give feedback on it and also share your own ideas in answers to make this discussion as fruitful as possible. My opinion is subject to change given convincing reasons, so I might edit these accordingly. This is intended to get the discussion started, not to be a call to vote on this special solution.

*1. Categories:*
I can see three categories:

- **The OP is not putting enough work into the question.** This includes showing one's work so far, where a clarification is needed ("I dont get it / need help")
- **The source of the question is unclear.** A source can be a book, stating that it's homework from course $C$ or that it resulted from some personal discussions. (I've seen quite a few questions of the form "I've seen on an internet forum that $A=B$. How is that?" with no link given, even after explicit request from fellow users)
- **The question isn't sufficiently self-contained.** Definitions used are possibly linked or given a reference to, but not all users may have access to this reference. Therefor a question should include all non-standard definitions it uses. Note that this is closer to unclear what you're asking than the other categories.

*2. Formulation:*
Suggestions for a suitable formulation for the three categories should be posted as an answer. I'll post a suggestion for a start but feel free to suggest one yourself.

Comment: If you, or others, write sufficiently good custom close reasons and suggest them on meta, the mod team will get together and consider making them available. I don't necessarily think it is or isn't likely, but it is certainly a possibility.

Comment: @mixedmath Thanks for the heads-up. Would this form (multiple new close reasons in one post) be sufficient? If so, I'd like to make this the goal of the post.

Comment: Just make it as clear and complete as possible, here or elsewhere. Keep in mind that comments are often great supplements to closure, and there is little reason for overly specific closure possibilities. In many ways, the SO model is a good model. They have significantly higher traffic and significantly more closures than we do, and in many cases what works for them will also work for us.

Comment: @mixedmath: How many custom reasons can there be?

Comment: Better suggestion: completely eliminate this highly overloaded closure path, which is too frequently abused to discriminate against valid mathematical questions  in every possible way imaginable.

Comment: Stay on topic, @Bill, this is a discussion about modifying the close reasons, not deleting them. As for the division proposed in the question, I'm not really sure that's the best possible. Besides, it only covers a few parts of what "missing context" covers. (I'm a bit too tired to suggest concrete improvements though).

Comment: @Najib Please read more closely. The OP specifically asked "Do we need less [such close reasons]?" I proposed less (zero). So my comment is most certainly on-topic.

Comment: For that matter, I've never liked that it's called "missing context or other details" but filed under "off-topic" when many times it is technically on topic but just missing details. Am I alone in this?

Comment: @AsafKaragila [Stack Overflow has five](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZY9aa.png), besides generic "not about [subject]" and  [migrate away]. This is probably as many as can fit into the form.

Comment: @CameronWilliams no you are not alone in this, but it is not possible to change this (except via a change of the software). It is a bit strange. But the way to make sense of it is that "off-topic" is jargon  for 'not suitable for the site (in its current form)' Note what is suitable is explained under "on-topic."

Comment: @Woodface: But SO always get a special treatment. So maybe the default settings is one or two, so I'm asking, essentially, without divine intervention, how many reasons can the moderators set?

Comment: @quid Well that's unsettling. I wasn't aware. Thanks for filling me in!

Comment: @Asaf the standard is three plus a default that is  non-selectable once there are custom ones. (Excluding migration and other of course.) The 'not about subject' would be one of the three as it is selectable // As this site is the second largest by new question one might hope for special treatement too.

Comment: @quid Bills suggestion was to remove (without replacement) the "missing context or other details" close reason. I don't think that's a good idea, but it certainly is a valid (as in on-topic) remark.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Three is the default mods can use without intervention from SE. But that is pretty much just a sanity check to prevent a site from going too far with overly specific close reasons. If there are good arguments for more close reasons, up to five are enabled. It's just generally a good idea to think a while before using all of the five, more close reasons are not always better.

Comment: @Mad Scientist: You don't have to sell me the idea that more choice is not necessarily a good thing.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Do you mind expanding on yesterday's comment and suggest improvements? I'm looking forward to hearing some feedback on the concrete suggestions.

Comment: @AlexR I'm in the train right now, writing on my phone isn't very practical... My main problem with your suggestions, I think, is that they rather focus on the symptoms than the underlying problems. Questions missing context are bad because they are of little value for a long term math knowledge depot. If you separate close reasons like that, it looks like every question has to meet these three criteria, but in reality a question has to miss all three to be bad, basically. I don't know if it's clear what I mean.

Comment: -1. This only makes easier the destruction of the site.

Comment: @MlazhinkaShungGronzalezLeWy in how far? Could you elaborate your concerns?

Comment: I doubt you'll get a coherent answer. The words "destruction", "off-topic comments", "unilateral actions"... have all become synonymous with "I don't like it" on meta.

Comment: @AlexR Tying in with the other three categories, there is also the stream of posts (particularly those asking multiple questions at once) which would benefit from detailing the scope: Is it about the specific example, the methods generally used with an application to the example, why a specific standard toolbox is insufficient, or something else altogether? Mostly this level can be estimated, but sometimes it's tricky to find the balance between full-fledged generality and custom-tailored argumentation.

Comment: @Lord_Farin I don't know how to categorize more than this "Multiple questions in one post" efficiently. Some are too broad, others have different problems and yet others could be split into legitimate stand-alone questions.

Comment: @AlexR My comment was more about the detailing of scope. That this often concerns multipart questions is relevant, but ultimately tangential.

Comment: @Lord_Farin Wouldn't that ultimately be te gap between too broad and the (now burned) too localized? If so, would you propose to add a "too localized" category?

Comment: May I request a category for "Your English is incoherent, please write this in your native language and ask for a translation" ?

Comment: @DanielV That category is "unclear what you're asking", if it's really unclear what is asked. Otherwise the question doesn't deserve to be closed. You can always leave a comment saying what you just wrote in addition to voting to close.

Comment: @AlexR Given the time people have had and the vote tally, I think we can proceed to the wording suggestions part.

Comment: @Lord_Farin I agree. I will try to come up with some good formulations. All others please post the suggestions as an answer to this question.

Comment: @Lord_Farin Okay I've written down some rough ones to start with. These are far from perfect, but at least we have something to improve on.

Comment: @mixedmath Should I create a new question for each custom close reason or does this format suffice?

Answer (score 3):

Here are my suggestions for the formulation. These are just a very rough mock-up - I'll be glad to incorporate specific suggestions / links etc. If you want to bigger changes, please consider writing your own answer, so the new formulation can be discussed independently.

**The OP is not putting enough work into the question**

> Your question is missing details on how *you* approached the problem, what you don't understand, **what you tried** so far and your **mathematical background**. This information can help others understand your difficulties with the problem and allows to write an answer suited for your understanding.

**The source of the question is unclear**

> The source of this question is unclear. Please add information on where you encountered the problem, possibly referencing a book or a website. Note that questions about on-going [contest problems](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16774/contest-problem-policy) are not allowed on this site and will be locked for the duration of the contest.

**The question isn't sufficiently self-contained**

> When asking a question here, you should try to make it as self-contained as possible. This includes paraphrasing the content of essential links to prevent link rot from making the question useless. Be aware that some definitions vary across different authors so writing down the definitions used in your reference or course can prevent confusion or useless answers.

Answer (score -5):

According to me "The source of the question is unclear. " is not a good reason to close a question. The source can be own studies.

Comment: "Source" does not mean it needs to be some external or "official" source. It is perfectly valid, and can be of value, to say: "This problem came up in my investigations on [something]" Fleshing out what this something is a bit.

Comment: @user48672 Of course, and this can be stated in the question so that the source of the question becomes clear.

Comment: That falls under the personal discussions part. For such questions it is beneficial to summarize how you got to the question, for example what you were working on when encountering the question. (For example: _I was reviewing some course work for $X$ when I noticed $Y$. Does this hold in general?_ instead of _Does $Y$ hold in general?_)

Comment: Under this formukation I agree.