# Why was my question unclear?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I wish to know why my question [Analyzing a definition of average which uses a variation of the Lebesgue integral and measure?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3683714/analyzing-a-definition-of-average-which-uses-a-variation-of-the-lebesgue-integra) was closed for being unclear. I believe I have fully clarified my definitions. I got rid of many confusing limits and tightly condensed my definitions.

I know the post is really long but it's like a summary of my research and I don't know where else to ask this. Please help if possible.

Thank You,

Bharath Krishnan

Comment: My [recent meta question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31865/addressing-community-specific-close-reasons-again) was motivated by questions like yours.  Your question is long includes a great deal of notation and computation, and never quite gets to the point.  Try to pare it down to one key idea, which you should be able to express in just one or two sentences.  If you can't do that, then it is exceedingly unlikely that your question will find a home here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The question you asked rather strikes me as "too broad", or as it is called now, 
it "needs more focus", as "[t]his question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only." But, I suppose one can also paraphrase that as it needing "clarity."

The site works best for relatively short, clear-cut problems. The site is not a good fit for that type of questions. The post is too long, and there are too many questions asked in one. This also has a result that the post was too frequently edited.

Unfortunately, the site cannot provide what you seem to seek with this post, namely an exchange and feedback about a mathematical activity of yours.

There is no specific issue with that post that you could address locally. The problem is more profound, in that the site is unsuitable for this type of posts.